# Extend one column of a data.table so that it will contain all integers from 1-50 when grouped with respect to another

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with the following (tidy-data format) columns

> Time-C1-C2-C3-C4

If it is groupped according to `Time` column, the column C1 currently contains some of integer value between 1-50, I want to extend that column so that if contains all the integer from 1 to 50 for each given `Time` value. I want to do this extension by filling the other columns of these new data point with `NA`. In other words, say the value `1` is missing from the C1 for `Time=1s`, then I'll add the following row to the dataset

```
Time-C1-C2-C3-C4

 1   1  NA NA NA
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `tidyr::complete(DT, Time, C1 = 1:50)`

Comment: Having `C1/2/3/4` across the page with a lot of NA values seems to be the exact opposite of a tidy, long-format dataset.